# node app is not working on digitalocean server

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean

i have clone a app to my droplet and now it is not working and nor showing any error I am new to programming can anybody help me to deploy it.
I have create droplet install node js,npm and mongodb on it and all are working,
my app.js code is
let port = 80;

```
      mongoose.connect(process.env.dbURI, dbOptions)
     .then((conn) => {
       app.listen(port,'165.22.223.8');
      console.log('connection success port:' +port);
  })
   .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect (!?) `165.22.223.8` is not the IP address of your DigitalOcean droplet. If that is the correct public IP address of the Droplet then, it's possible that you've not configured the Droplet's firewall to permit traffic on port 80. See debugging below.

> **NOTE** Ports <1024 (i.e. `80`) require root. It's possible that this is another issue you're facing. You may wish to try (the commonly used) `8080` instead of `80` while you're developing. If you do, replace occurrences of `80` with `8080` in what follows.

The command `app.listen` attempts to bind the Express server to that specific IP address on `port`.

I think you'll be able to avoid specifying the host name entirely and just use:

```js
app.listen(port);
```

To debug (either scenario), ssh onto the Droplet and try `curl`ing the localhost's port 80 (assuming that is indeed the value of `port`) i.e.:

```sh
HOST="localhost"
PORT="80" # Or 8080 

curl \
--request GET \
http://${HOST}:${PORT}
```

When that succeeds, you can then try accessing the server remotely. You'll need to determine the Droplet's public IP address and then:

```sh
HOST=[[REPLACE-WITH-DROPLET-IP]]
PORT="80" # Or 8080

curl \
--request GET \
http://${HOST}:${PORT}
```

Comment: this answer is working guys but i cant vote it because it says I have 15 reputations to vote